# jquery not grabing the value from <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function which will add and remove products from a list.

```
$("#basketItemsWrap li img").live("click", function (event) {
    $("#notificationsLoader").html('<img src="http://images/loader.gif">');

    var oid = $("#thelist li").attr('id').split('_')[1];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://index.php/action/delete",
        data: {
            officeID: oid,
            action: "delete"
        },
        success: function (theResponse) {

            $("#officeID_" + oid).hide("slow", function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $("#notificationsLoader").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML code

```
<div id="basketItemsWrap">
<ul id="thelist">
<li></li>
<?php echo getBasket(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

The html output is

```
<li id="officeID_15669">Office 1</li>
<li id="officeID_14903">Office</l 2i>
```

I want to get the id from the `<li>` split and get the number so I can pass the value to the database.

```
    var oid = $("#thelist li").attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

When i click, the `oid` is always undefined. What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: which version of jquery are you using..?

Comment: @Razor im using version 1.9.1

Comment: well u might get answer now :), `live()` is no longer part of jquery api as of version 1.9 and above. use `on()` or `delegate()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#thelist li")` selects all list elements in #thelist, and the first one is `<li></li>`. `attr('id')` is applied to the first one and is therefore undefined.

Use this inside the click handler:

```
var oid = $(this).parent("li").attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this help you :

```
$("#basketItemsWrap li img").on("click", function(event) { 

$("#notificationsLoader").html('<img src="http://images/loader.gif">');

     var attrid =  $(this).parent().attr('id'); 
    var oid = attrid.split('_')[1]);

    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "http://index.php/action/delete",   
    data: {officeID: oid, action: "delete"},  
    success: function(theResponse) {

        $("#officeID_" + oid).hide("slow",  function() {$(this).remove();});
        $("#notificationsLoader").empty();

    }  
    });  

});
```

i create a live example for you (but without ajax function) : 
http://jsbin.com/ozepoh/2/

Answer (score 1):

When you use `var oid = $("#thelist li").attr('id').split('_')[1];` it always get the `id` of the first `li` in the list instead of the `id` of `li` which was clicked.

You can get the clicked `li` using `$(this).parent()`.

```
$("#basketItemsWrap").live("click", 'li img', function (event) {
    $("#notificationsLoader").html('<img src="http://images/loader.gif">');

    var oid = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('_')[1];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://index.php/action/delete",
        data: {
            officeID: oid,
            action: "delete"
        },
        success: function (theResponse) {

            $("#officeID_" + oid).hide("slow", function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $("#notificationsLoader").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its undefined because of the li in bold

```
<div id="basketItemsWrap">
<ul id="thelist">
**<li></li>**
<?php echo getBasket(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

as visible it has got no id attribute so $("#thelist li") selects this one and then $("#thelist li").attr('id') leads to undefined